# Some using directives are not working in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[image]Some 'using' directives in controller are disabled in MVC5. So i could't call Models folder in controller. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `namespace` used in `ML_ProductModel.cs` file is the same as in your `using` statement, or even that a `namespace` clause exists in the class file.

Also make sure that the project containing `ML_ProductModel.cs` is set to be built before this project (if necessary edit project build order).